# jquery-ui resizable save changes to local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have an accordion (using jquery-ui) that is resizable. I would like to save user changes so if the page refreshes the accordion will remain in the same size\position. After doing some research it seems localstorage is the best way to handle this. Any help would be appreciated as I'm completely confused. Below is my javascript function:

```
<script>
 $( function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  heightStyle: "fill"
});

$( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({
  handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw',
  minHeight: 140,
  minWidth: 200,
  resize: function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
  }
});
 } );
</script>

   <script>
   if (typeof String.prototype.start_with != 'function') {
   String.prototype.start_with = function (str){
   return this.slice(0, str.length) == str;
   };
    }
         function inspect(e, options) {
     if(options==null){
     options = {};
  } 
  var onlykey = options['onlykey']==null ? false : options['onlykey']
   var prefix = options['prefix']==null ? '' : options['prefix']
   var msg = new Array();
    for (prop in e) {
                if(prop.start_with(prefix)){
       if(onlykey==true){
    msg.push(prop);
                          }else{
    msg.push(prop + ": " + e[prop]);
           }
             }

           };

                    if(onlykey==true){
              $("#cl").html(msg.join(', '));
      }else{
                   $("#cl").html(msg.join('\n'));
                              } 

              }
             var set_position = function(width, height){
                       $('.ui-resizable-n').css('left', (width/2-                   4)+'px');
       $('.ui-resizable-e').css('top', (height/2-4)+'px');
              $('.ui-resizable-s').css('left', (width/2-4)+'px');
           $('.ui-resizable-w').css('top', (height/2-4)+'px');
};
$( ".box" ).resizable({ 
 handles: {
'n':'.ui-resizable-n', 
'e':'.ui-resizable-e',
's':'.ui-resizable-s',
'w':'.ui-resizable-w',
'ne': '.ui-resizable-ne',
'se': '.ui-resizable-se',
'sw': '.ui-resizable-sw',
'nw': '.ui-resizable-nw'
   },
  grid: [ 10, 10 ],
  //helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
  create: function( event, ui ) {
   //alert(ui.element);
   //inspect(event.target, {'onlykey':true});

       var width = $(event.target).width();
   var height = $(event.target).height();
  set_position(width, height);
 },
 resize: function(event, ui){
       var width = $(event.target).width();
var height = $(event.target).height();
set_position(width, height);
},
alsoResize: "#rect1" 
});

   $( ".box" ).draggable({
 grid: [ 10, 10 ]
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Michelle, please share your HTML code to debug easily

Comment: Everything is contained within <div id="accordion-resizer"> </div>

Comment: Michelle, please edit your post and add your relevant HTML markup (ALL the HTML that you use to create your accordion) to it.  You're not just referencing a div called "accordion-resizer"; there's also a reference to "accordion" in your code.  And unless I'm less familiar with accordions than I think I am, there have to be some `h3` elements in there as well.